# elasticsearch insert objects into index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and looking for a bit of help using the Java API.  I have some domain objects 
E.g.

```
@XmlRootElement

public class BasicActivity {

private String activityName;
private FullActivity activity;  
// Getters and setters
}
```

I have created a transport client connected to a node

```
Client client = new TransportClient()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("192.168.0.198",9300));
```

**Is there and easy way to insert my object straight into elasticsearch?**

I have seen this

```
IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
                    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                                .startObject()
                                    .field("user", "kimchy")
                                    .field("postDate", new Date())
                                    .field("message", "trying out Elastic     Search")
                                .endObject()
                              )
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
```

But to do that I would have to convert every object into json, which while possible is not my ideal situation.

If I have a misunderstanding of how it works (architecturally) then please let me know, I am here to learn!

cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.  The Java API can be hard to get at times when you are not used to it.  I think over time it will get better.

You do have to convert your objects to Json to send them to your ElasticSearch cluster.  [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is one of many popular libraries out there that can do that for you.

The code you show above will create an index.  Now to add a document to that index, run something like this.

```
   Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
   tweet.setId("1234");
   tweet.setMessage("message");

   IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("twitter","tweet", tweet.getId());
   indexRequest.source(new Gson().toJson(tweet));
   IndexResponse response = client.index(indexRequest).actionGet();
```

Check out [BulkRequest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-bulk.html) for indexing several items at once.  Once your objects get more complex, you'll need to create [Mappings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping.html).

I have found great examples in the [Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/), but usually more detailed examples in the [ES Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/elasticsearch).

I have to recommend the [Head](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) front end, too.  It shows you existing indices and items.

Comment: Jackson is another Json library,  it seems to compare favorably to Gson in terms of performance.  http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial

Comment: Is there any way of adding it without converting the object to json ?